# How to make layout with a color bar behind text and image

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, layout, border

Im trying to create this layout (sorry for the quality, it's all what I have):
[image]

So far I have built this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:padding="12dp">
    <ImageView xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:layout_width="48dp"
        android:layout_height="48dp"
        android:id="@+id/UserPhotoImageView"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_marginRight="16dp" />
    <TextView
        android:text="UserName"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textStyle="normal"
        android:typeface="normal"
        android:textSize="16dp"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/UserPhotoImageView"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/CalendarImageView"
        android:id="@+id/UserNameTextView"
        android:textColor="#333333" />
    <TextView
        android:text="Date"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:typeface="normal"
        android:textSize="12dp"
        android:id="@+id/DateTextView"
        android:gravity="top"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/CalendarImageView"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/CalendarImageView" />
    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="16dp"
        android:layout_height="16dp"
        android:gravity="top"
        android:id="@+id/CalendarImageView"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_marginLeft="6dp"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_calendar_icon"
        android:backgroundTint="#ffffffff" />
    <TextView
        android:text="Comment"
        android:layout_below="@+id/UserNameTextView"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/UserNameTextView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:typeface="normal"
        android:textSize="14dp"
        android:id="@+id/UserCommentTextView" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Which give me the first part as I want to achive this:
[image]

Now for the last row, I know how to make a rounded image but how can i place the image and the text behind a colored bar?

Answer (score 2):

I would create a `RelativeLayout` for this part (circle image with color bar and text)

you can add a `View` (could be an `ImageView`) in this relative layout, to show behind your image. and give it background with color of your choice.

Example:

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent" 
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"> <!--change here to what you need-->

    <!--your colored bar-->

    <View
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="30dp" <!--control the thickness of your bar-->
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:background="#3333aa" />

    <!--face image-->

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageFace"
        android:layout_width="70dp"
        android:layout_height="70dp"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_marginRight="15dp"
        android:background="@color/#2323ea" />

    <!--text view-->

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_marginRight="15dp"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@id/imageFace"
        android:text="name" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

add your own customizations but this is a general example

Comment: thanks, isnt imageview for the bar a little heavy?is it common to use imageview for bars,lines etc?

Comment: it may be little heavier (but you won't notice it ever), that is why i used in this example a `View`. but if you want more options on your bar, `ImageView` could be better.

Answer (score 1):

Wrap both in a `FrameLayout`.

I guessed at the dimensions, but this should get you in the ballpark.

```
        <FrameLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/UserCommentTextView">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/name"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                android:paddingTop="8dp"
                android:paddingBottom="8dp"
                android:paddingRight="96dp"
                android:gravity="right|end"
                android:background="@color/purple"
                tools:text="Name"/>

            <!-- replace with whatever component you are using for circle image view -->
            <CircleImageView
                android:id="@+id/circle_image_view"
                android:layout_width="64dp"
                android:layout_height="64dp"
                android:layout_gravity="right|end"
                android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
                android:background="@color/purple"
                tools:src="@drawable/gwynneth"/>

        </FrameLayout>
```

---

EDIT

Alternatively, if you wanted to eliminate the `FrameLayout`, you could integrate those two views right into your `RelativeLayout` with these changes:

- For the positioning, I would go with `android:layout_alignParentTop="true"` and then a top margin to push the views down beneath your other views.  You have a slight issue in that you want these to be below both the user image and the comment text, but since the comment text could expand so the bottom is lower than the image, it's hard to say which view you should anchor on.  You might want to set a `maxHeight` on the comment to keep it from getting too big.
- Since you don't have the `FrameLayout` to center on anymore, you would have to give the `TextView` an absolute size in order to line it up with the circle image view.  If you're okay with that, you can just put these right in your `RelativeLayout` then set their top margins so that they align correctly:

  ```
          <TextView
              android:id="@+id/name"
              android:layout_width="match_parent"
              android:layout_height="32dp"
              android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
              android:layout_marginTop="80dp"
              android:paddingTop="8dp"
              android:paddingBottom="8dp"
              android:paddingRight="96dp"
              android:paddingEnd="96dp"
              android:gravity="right|end"
              android:background="@color/purple"
              tools:text="Name"/>

          <!-- replace with whatever component you are using for circle image view -->
          <CircleImageView
              android:id="@+id/circle_image_view"
              android:layout_width="64dp"
              android:layout_height="64dp"
              android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
              android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
              android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
              android:layout_marginTop="64dp"
              android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
              android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
              android:background="@color/purple"
              tools:src="@drawable/gwynneth"/>
  ```

Comment: thanks, i cant understand in this code where the bar is displayed

Comment: Fixed some errors... See at the top, it has `android:layout_below="@+id/UserCommentTextView"` this would go inside your `RelativeLayout`.  Working on cleaning it up a bit right now

Comment: The top and bottom margin should have been padding, fixed that... this looks exactly like your picture

Comment: which code creates the line bar? the textview? clever

Comment: its ok if i use this layout for many many comments? i mean its not heavy?

Comment: It doesn't seem heavy to me, but ultimately you have to be the one to decide.  It's certainly not as heavy as the other answers recommending you to use a `RelativeLayout` then *three* internal views.  And keep in mind, if you're using a `RecyclerView` or `ListView`, you only have a handful of views when displaying all those comments thanks to recycling.

Comment: If you're concerned about the extra layout, I edited the answer to offer an alternative so that you could put the two views directly into your `RelativeLayout` and eliminate that `FrameLayout`.

Answer (score 0):

So I understand that you want to draw that purple thick line and put on top of it a Imageview.
The easiest way, the whay i usually do to overlapp two or more layouts/ views is this: lets say we have 3 views( View 1, View 2 and View 3). If you put them in this order(1,2,3)in a Relative layout, and set them the same position  in the Layout, the result will be that the View 3 will be on top of other 2.

So as a conclusion, if you want to overlapp two or more Views just put the View you want to be on top( the picture in your case) before the view you want to be overlapped( the purple line)